# Angular 8 Material table @ViewChild in NgOnInit lifecycle hook undefined even with static true option

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular8

I have a simple Angular 8 component with Material Table. The code was mostly copied directly from the official docs [Material Table sorting example](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

The console error message appears `ERROR Error: Cannot read property 'sortChange' of undefined`.

According to this [github thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/28810), the option `static: true` should enable the query results to be available in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook.

However, it is still throwing the error. This DOES work when using `ngAfterViewInit`, however, I want to be able to set boolean values that affect the view such as `isLoading = true`, so I need the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook to avoid the `expression changed after it has been checked` error message.

Here is a [simple stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-azzvp3), open the browser error console to see the error message.

```
  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true}) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => {console.log('sort change')});
  }

  // Load data from API 
  // Set boolean values that affect the view such as isLoading
```

Comment: That is not the problem you have in `stackblitz` example. There `this.sort` is `undefined` even in `ngAfterViewInit` (so it doesn't work). But, if in your real example it works, you should know that if the content cannot be resolved statically (e.g. there is `*ngIf` or similar structure directive on that element) then the content will NOT be available in `ngOnInit` even if you use `static: true`. [reference](https://blog.ninja-squad.com/2019/05/29/what-is-new-angular-8.0/#queries-timing)

Comment: Additionally, based on your error, the `this.sort` variable is not an issue, but `sortChange` event emitter. You can use `(matSortChange)` in your template instead of `sortChange` if you need that feature...

Comment: @miselking Thanks! I took a closer look at the example in the Angular Material docs and I copied the material-module code to my stackblitz and it works now. So I must've been missing a module somewhere.

Comment: Hmm it still doesn't work in my project so I must be missing something somewhere.